# Cannot suppress CA1903:UseOnlyApiFromTargetedFramework

Tags: c#, fxcop, suppressmessage

FxCop is telling me the following:

> "Assembly
>   'ILRetail.eBusiness.Common.WebUtility.dll'
>   has a reference to assembly
>   'System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, 
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. 
>   Because this assembly was introduced
>   in .NET Framework 
>   3.5 Service Pack 1, which is higher than the project's  target framework,
>   .NET Framework 3.5, your application 
>   may fail to run on systems without
>   this framework installed."

To try to suppress this, I have the following line in my assembly.cs:

```
[module: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Portability", "CA1903:UseOnlyApiFromTargetedFramework", MessageId = "System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35")]
```

I can suppress this message in other projects, just not this one.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you added the CODE_ANALYSIS compilation symbol.

Comment: Worked a charm, had done this previously on my other projects and promptly forgotten